# trying to replace a field name using a variable at run time in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let me preface that I have searched this question and tried a ton of things but I am obviously missing something simple (I think).

I believe my solution will involve reflection but I just can't get it right.

**Edit**: 
Quicker question - I need to replace the .fieldname of a query result with a string.  So `var value = stops.First().con_name;`  the `.con_name` needs to be dynamic at run time.

Basics:
I am creating the ability to generate custom reports from a database where the report layout is stored in a table of column names, column position and field names.

So the below is the data for a very simple report:

```
record 1
col_index  - 17
field_name - con_name

record 2
col_index -  18
field_name-  con_city
```

I am needing to query a table called `stop_details` for a collection of records that are to be included in the report.

I then want to query a table called `report_matrix` that will return the above records (the two sample records I gave).

I then need to step through the matrix results and create the columns based on the data.

The challenge is replacing the field_name at run time.
So in the below code on the first run through it would have `var value = stops.First().con_name;`  the second time .con_name would be replaced with `.con_city` etc....

Here is my code:

```
     //get collection of stops for export

        var stops = (from s in db.stop_details 
                     where s.eCourier_export_flag == true 
                     select s)
                     .ToArray();

        //pull in all the report format details

        var reportLayout = (from r in db.report_matrix 
                            where r.report_id == 1 
                            select r)
                            .ToArray();

        //just do one line

        foreach (var layoutElement in reportLayout)
        {                
            // Select the PropertyInfo of the column.
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = 
              stops.First().GetType().GetProperty(layoutElement.field_name);
            // name = stops.GetValue(propertyInfo, null).ToString();
            // HERE is where I need to replace .con_name with the field name from the query
            var value = stops.First().con_name; 
         }
```

Thank you in advance for any help....
Joe

Comment: Thank you Alexander...I see what you mean formatting wise now.  I will work on that in the future and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `GetValue` method of `PropertyInfo`:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = 
          stops.First().GetType().GetProperty(layoutElement.field_name);
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(stops.First());
```